# Constrained Optimization Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, optimization, keras, neural-network

I have a trained classifier neural network in Keras. Let the neural network be f(x). I want to find the vectors x such that when ||x||^2 = 1, f(x) is maximized.  I currently have trained my neural network with Keras

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(500, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(500, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam',  metrics=['accuracy', auc])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_data=(x_test, y_test), epochs=2, verbose = 1, callbacks=[earlyStopping])
```

I want to know if there is a way to solve this constrained optimization problem once my Neural network has already been trained. There is a scipy optimize which can do this for general functions. Is there a way to do this for a neural network. Please include a code sample.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you have finished training your neural network and would like to find the input `x` which maximizes the probability of it being in a certain class (where the output is close to 1.0)

You could write a small function to assess the performance of your network using the `predict_proba()` method to get classification probabilities on test data, and then optimise this function using scipy:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(500, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(500, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam',  metrics=['accuracy', auc])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_data=(x_test, y_test), epochs=2, verbose = 1, callbacks=[earlyStopping])

def f(x):
    prediction = model.predict_proba(x)
    return -prediction

a = scipy.optimize.minimize(f, x0=np.random.randn(500))
optimal_x = a.x
```

`optimal_x` will be the input `x` which maximises the certainty with which your classifier puts it in one specific class.

Comment: I am not trying to find the optimal data set. I am trying to find the single data points x that maximize a pretrained f(x). f(x) is just evaluating the neural network. It only depends on x.

Comment: maximize what though? f(x) produces a set of outputs, one for each category. What are you trying to maximise? x is your data.

Comment: F just produces a probability. It is a classifier.

Comment: Okay, i see what is happening. It is a binary classifier, so 1 for class A, 0 for class B. And you want to find the data point which is most strongly classified into class A?

Comment: Yes that is exactly